# Modern Objective-C (2013) and declaring ivars/using @property, @dynamic, and @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, oop, instance-variables

With the current version of Objective-C, what are the official standards and best practices for declaring ivars, using `@property` and `@synthesize`? There are a lot of posts and resources on the topic but most of them are fairly antiquated from a year or two ago. I recently learned to only declare ivars in a statement block in the implementation of a class so that the encapsulation principles of OOP aren't broken but is declaring ivars even necessary in this day and age? What would be a possible use case where doing:

```
@interface MyClass()
@property (nonatomic) NSString* data;
@end

@implementation MyClass{
    @private
        NSString* _data;
}
@end
```

is necessary? To further that, is it ever necessary to use `@synthesize`? My understanding is that using `@property` will auto-synthesize both the accessor methods as well as the backing ivars. I've done some experimentation and I noticed that when I don't declare `NSString* _data', I can still access`_data' in my class implementation. Does that mean that declaring ivars come down to a matter of style, up to the discretion of the programmer? Could I condense my code and remove all ivar declarations in the statement blocks in my implementation and just use `@property` in my private interface? If that's not the case, what are the advantages and disadvantages of explicitly declaring ivars?

Finally, `@dynamic`. From what I can gather, it's used to say to the compiler, "Hey compiler, don't auto-generate the accessor method and don't worry if you don't find an implementation for it, I'll provide one at runtime". Is that all `@dynamic` is used for or is there more to it?

I just want to clarify all these things because it seems like there's a lot of different opinions and that there's not necessarily one right answer. Plus as Objective-C grows and progresses, those answers will change so it'll be nice to have a concise and up-to-date guide. Thanks everyone! 
(Also if there's anything that I could word better or make clearer, let me know)

EDIT:

In summary, what I'm asking is this:

1) Is declaring ivars with modern Objective-C necessary?
2) Can I achieve the same effects of declaring ivars and corresponding properties by just using `@property`?
3) What is @dynamic used for?
4) Can I completely forgo the use of `@synthesize` or is there a good use case for it?

Upvote and down vote as you see fit.

Comment: I recommend watching some WWDC materials :- WWDC 2012 [Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405)
- WWDC 2012 [Migrating to Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=413)
- [Clang Language Extensions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html)

Comment: FWIW, I'd go further than the others have and suggest that not only are explicitly declared ivars not generally required anymore, but that they're inadvisable (unless you need backward compatibility for some reason, e.g. writing a library to be shared with others). But I've seen too many problems here on Stack Overflow stemming from the innocuous mismatch between some explicitly declared ivar and the automatically synthesized one (though there is a new compiler warning that helps identify these cases).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a lot to answer here. I'll break it down:

### Declaring ivars

As you've correctly noted, modern versions of the compiler will synthesize backing instance variables for declared @properties. The exception to this is on 32-bit Macs, where the modern Objective-C runtime, including non-fragile instance variables, is not available. Assuming your application is not targeting 32-bit OS X, you don't need to explicitly declare the backing ivar for an `@property`.

If you still want to use an ivar directly, without a corresponding `@property` (something I consider a bad idea most of the time), you of course must still explicitly declare the ivar.

### @dynamic

`@dynamic` is as you've said meant to tell the compiler "don't synthesize accessors for this property, I'll do it myself at runtime". It's not used all that often. One place it is used is in `NSManagedObject` subclasses, where if you declare a modeled property in the header, you don't want to compiler to complain that there's no implementation of accessors for that property, nor do you want it to generate accessors itself. `NSManagedObject` generates accessors for modeled properties at runtime. The story is similar for custom CALayer subclasses.

### @synthesize

`@synthesize` explicitly tells the compiler to synthesize accessor methods, and (on iOS and 64-bit Mac) a corresponding ivar for the specified property. There are three main cases where you still need to use it:

1. 32-bit Mac apps.
2. If you've written your own custom setter and getter (or just getter for readonly properties). In this case, the compiler won't synthesize accessors because it sees yours. However, it also won't synthesize the backing ivar. So, you must use `@synthesize someProperty = _someProperty;`, to tell the compiler to synthesize an ivar. It still won't synthesize accessor methods of course. Alternatively, you can explicitly declare a backing ivar. I favor using `@synthesize` in this case.
3. If you want to use a different name for the property's backing ivar than the default (property name with an added underscore prefix). This is rare. The main case I can think of for using it is when transitioning existing, older code, that includes direct ivar access and where the ivars are not underscore-prefixed.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that a use case in favor of declaring ivars is to use `@private`, `@protected`, and `@public` to declare the scope of those properties for subclasses and stuff? If I didn't declare the ivars, how would I set the scope to `@protected` for example?

Comment: Yes, although those scope specifiers are rarely used in Objective-C. It's essentially never a good idea to expose ivars `@public`ly. You should have a public `@property` instead. `@protected` can be useful in certain narrow cases, but even then, having subclasses use ("protected") property accessors is usually a better approach.

Comment: Ok so final question. I'm a huge fan of lazy instantiation where if I declare `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* string;` with a corresponding ivar `NSString* _string`, in my implementation I override the getter like this: `- (NSString*)string{ if(!_string){ //do something} return _string;}`. I just went through one of my classes and removed all the ivars and now I can't access any of my properties with _propertyName. Is there any other way to accomplish lazy instantiation without declaring ivars for every property?

Comment: You also have to use @synthesize if you have some non-persistant properties in a NSManagedObject.

Comment: @shadow, that's item #2 under `@synthesize` in my answer. If you're overriding both accessors (or just the getter for a readonly property), the compiler doesn't generate an ivar for you. You must either explicitly declare it, or use an `@synthesize` statement (`@synthesize` is my preferred approach).

Comment: @paulrehkugler, good point. The compiler actually avoids auto synthesis of declared `@properties` in NSManagedObject with recent (iOS 6+, 10.8+?) versions of the SDKs. So, you have to explicitly use @synthesize in these cases. Alternatively, you can put non-persistent attributes in the model, by marking them transient. Then, NSManagedObject will generate accessors at runtime just as with persistent modeled attribute.

Comment: Do you have a source for the requirement for `@synthesize` on 32-bit Mac apps? I've never heard of that requirement and to the best of my knowledge, it is a compiler feature. Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: @Neal, See the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/). It is a compiler feature, but it also requires the support for non-fragile instance variables that is included in the "modern runtime", which is only available on 64-bit Macs (and all iOS devices). Also see the [10.5 Objective-C Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/RN-ObjectiveC/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004309-CH1-DontLinkElementID_10)

Answer (score 1):

First off, @synthesize is gone for these scenarios: do not have to do it any more.

Secondly, you don't need the private ivar anymore either.

So in essence, you can just do properties.

The way of controlling access is the same idiom that had become popular before MOC dropped: put the property in the public interface as readonly and then make a readwrite version in the private interface (which should be, as you show above, merely the name with open and close parens).

Note also, that many of the things that cluttered up the public interface in the past can now ONLY be in the private interface, so for instance IBOutlets, etc., since the controller is going to be the only thing diddling them.

I never see @dynamic used anywhere except in CoreDate-generated entities.

For someone who first worked with C++ where the dream was always that the header/interface merely show the user of the class what they needed and all other details would be hidden, I think MOC (Modern Objective C) is a dream come true.

BTW, highly recommend the intro session from WWDC Modern Objective C (from 2012) and the one this year was great too.

Comment: In most part I agree but if for some reason you need your ivar to have different name than standard `_name` then you need to manually call synthesize.

Comment: What's MOC? I'm not familiar with that term. The google wasn't super helpful either

Comment: `@synthesize` is not gone: In the unusual circumstance where you define both your own custom setter and getter (or for `readonly`, your own getter), you have to synthesize the property if you want the ivar to be synthesized for you. Otherwise, in this situation, the compiler will not synthesize the ivar for you. (btw, different Rob, lol)

Comment: @Rob, I'm assuming that in the case that I define my own custom setter and getter/`readonly`, that Xcode will throw a compiler warning or error? I feel like I've seen that once or twice.

Comment: When you have a private interface, doesn't it mean that your subclasses won't be able to access your readwrite property?

Comment: @Rob gone as in not required for what he was asking for. The scenario I described of a public readonly and private readwrite will also not require a synthesize.

Comment: @shadow, if you define your own custom accessors and don't use `@synthesize`, Xcode will throw an error if you try to access the (non-existent) backing instance variable. Of course, sometimes an `@property` isn't directly backed by a simple ivar at all, in which case `@synthesize` is again not necessary. This a scenario that explains one reason why the compiler won't automatically generate an ivar for a property with custom accessors.

Answer (score 1):

Best current practice seems to be to use properties for all ivars placing the property either in the .h file if they are to be exposed and in the .m file in a class extension if local to the class.

No `@synthesize` is needed unless the ivar needs to be different than the underscore prepended property name.

Yes, `@dynamic` is as you describe.

Further, it is no longer necessary to declare local instance methods or order such that the method is above the use.